# sql query updates all rows and not only where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble executing this query:

```
update public.fortune_companies 
set industry_id = (select id 
                   from public.industries 
                   where name = 'Agriculture, Forestry and Fishing') 
from Temp_Sic_Fortune_Companies as temp 
left join public.fortune_companies as fc on fc.account_name = temp.account_name
where temp.sic between '0' and '499';
```

I think this is supposed to set the industry_id for only ones that have a sic number of 0-499 but it actually sets every record to the same id. No matter if the sic number is between 0-499 or not.

Why is this.

Comment: `'0'`, `'499'` are a character literals ("Strings") not numbers. `0` and `499` are numbers (note the absence of the quotes).

Comment: I have tried it without the quotes but the Between operator complains because I entered the number as a string column. This was a necessary step.

Comment: You know that '3000' is between '0' and '499' right?

Comment: No i did not. How can i make this work with the string numbers

Comment: Never ever store numbers in character columns. Just don't

Comment: Both temp.sic and expressions in the between have to have same type. Could you try converting temp.sic to int and then remove the quotes? As Aaron is saying there is A LOT betwwen '0' and '499'

Comment: I removed the quotes and changed it to int. I still get the same result but that was part of the problem. Thanks for all the help so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @id INT;

SELECT @id = id 
  FROM public.industries 
  WHERE name = 'Agriculture, Forestry and Fishing';

UPDATE fc
  SET industry_id = @id
  FROM public.fortune_companies AS fc
  WHERE EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 
      FROM dbo.Temp_Sic_Fortune_Companies
      WHERE account_name = fc.account_name
      AND sic BETWEEN '0' and '499'
  );
```

Of course, if `temp.sic` = `'3000'`, it will be part of the set. This is one of the dangers of using the wrong data type (or the wrong operator). You can fix that by saying:

```
AND sic BETWEEN '0' and '499'
AND LEN(sic) <= 3
```

Or by saying:

```
AND CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(sic) = 1 THEN 
  CONVERT(INT, sic) ELSE -1 END BETWEEN 0 AND 499
```

(This avoids errors if - since you've let them - someone enters a non-numeric value into the column.)

Or by using the right data type in the first place.

Comment: I have them as int now but i get this error: ERROR: relation "fc" does not exist
  Position:

Comment: I got this working now but it produces the same result. All rows are updated

Comment: Then you need to show sample data from both tables and identify the rows you want updated. We are throwing darts at the wall here based on the query in the question.

Comment: I would like to help but I am not supposed to show the data online. Any specific questions about it? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `left join` to `inner join`

Comment: That still had the same effect

Comment: How many companies have a sic between 0 and 499? If you try putting a `select *` on top of your `from` you can see the rows it wants to update. The left join would have always resulted in all rows being updated. The inner at least makes it function as you want to it here.